# Fail to manage Core Data in Models other than AppDelegate.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

```
- (void)doneButtonPressed
{
    //判断已存在这个title的proj的话不创建

    //存储CD数据
    Project *newProject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    //!!!!crash here!!!!
    newProject.title = self.titleTextField.text;
    newProject.subtitle = self.subtitleTextField.text;
    newProject.progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    newProject.pid = @"001";

    NSError* savingError = nil;
    if (newProject != nil){
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]){
            NSLog(@"Saved!");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Fail to save the proj");
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Fail to create new proj");
    }
}
```

I simply add these code into my `CertainViewController.m` and found that I could not save things into the core data.

Here below shows the reason:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Project''

Do I miss some pre-setting in the `CertainViewController`?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSEntityDescription *entityDescription;
```

I do include these two property into the .h and synthesize them in the `.m`.

Will really appreciate your answer;)

Comment: `//判断已存在这个title的proj的话不创建` - Ah, now it's clear! I see what you're trying to do there!

Comment: just ignore the Chinese cuz it is unrelated to the problem

Comment: How/Where do you setup the context (`self.managedObjectContext`) of the controller? how do you setup your store coordinator?

Comment: Does ist help if you first modify the object and insert it after that in you moc?

Comment: @DanShelly I set it up in the AppDelegate;)

Comment: But did you ever set the value of `CertainViewController`'s `managedObjectContext` property? Setting it up in the app delegate doesn't automatically assign it to a view controller's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. you have not set your context properly.

If i guess correctly (and I do cause I tested it), you have only `alloc` `init` your context like so:
`self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext] alloc] init];`

A context defined like this is orphaned as it does not have a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` or `parentContext` to get to the persistent store from.

You should either pass the context from the previous view controller, or set it up yourself:

```
//Example:
AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:<#(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)#>];
[self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

Comment: thanks a lot that I finally figure out to solve the problem;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following steps:

1. Try delete app from simulator or Device after run
2. Check the below tutorials,
   http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started
   http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/